# Problems with entering Git commit message with Vim

Tags: git, commit, message

OS: Windows

I write

```
$ git commit
```

then

> "# Please enter the commit message"

I write some text, like

> "Form validation added"

Press Enter and not commited. Then i press Shift+Enter, Ctrl+Enter, Alt+Enter - still not commited.

I think its stupid trouble, but What i must to do?

Comment: No problem. But your question would probably get better attention over at Super User, which is more on-topic for this type of non-programming question: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/git

Answer (score 255, accepted):

If it is VIM for Windows, you can do the following:

- enter your message following the presented guidelines
- press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to make sure you are out of the insert mode
- then type `:wq`<kbd>Enter</kbd> or `ZZ`.

Note that in VIM there are often several ways to do one thing. Here there is a slight difference though. `:wq`<kbd>Enter</kbd> always writes the current file before closing it, while `ZZ`, `:x`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, `:xi`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, `:xit`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, `:exi`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and `:exit`<kbd>Enter</kbd> only write it if the document is *modified*.
All these synonyms just have different numbers of keypresses.

Comment: Linked: [What to do after typing in commit message for git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048859/what-to-do-after-typing-in-commit-message-for-git)

Comment: When I enter `:wq` I see following message, ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" 54L, 2316C written Aborting commit due to empty commit message.

Comment: Make sure you've added a message. When prompted type something like "my message here" (you'll go into --insert mode-- I assume, press esc to leave it). Once you're done, and out of insert mode, then type 'ZZ' (capital ZZ)

Comment: Why, who came up with this? :wq Enter or ZZ sounds insane.

Comment: the `i` command to start inserting message text was extremely helpful.  Thanks to @Matt Greer for that one.  This answer was good for the rest of the steps.

Comment: Really helpful. So you need to go into insert mode, type your message, then hit esc, then type :wq. I wouldn't have figured it out and VIM is the default editor that comes up for me when using a new macbook pro.

Answer (score 48):

I am assuming you are using msys git. If you are, the editor that is popping up to write your commit message is vim. Vim is not friendly at first. You may prefer to switch to a different editor. If you want to use a different editor, look at this answer: [How do I use Notepad++ (or other) with msysgit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634161/how-do-i-use-notepad-or-other-with-msysgit/1635493#1635493)

If you want to use vim, type `i` to type in your message. When happy hit ESC. Then type `:wq`, and git will then be happy.

Or just type `git commit -m "your message here"` to skip the editor altogether.

Comment: Is vim *ever* friendly?  Or do people just get used to its unfriendliness?

Comment: vim is friendly once you understand how it works. It's actually very logical and well thought out.

Comment: If I want to use characters that require escaping (e.g. apostrophes) in the commit message I always use the vim editor because it's way less annoying. Otherwise I almost always just write the commit message as part of the commit command.

Comment: This is great when you need to amend a commit message

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried just going:
git commit -m "Message here"

So in your case:

```
git commit -m "Form validation added"
```

After you've added your files of course.

Comment: Your variant good. But I want to go the way of what I wrote (google Translator)

Comment: No worries, I forgot that there was an editor after that command. I rarely ever just do git commit without an -m "Message"

Answer (score 1):

Typically, `git commit` brings up an interactive editor (on Linux, and possibly Cygwin, determined by the contents of your `$EDITOR` environment variable) for you to edit your commit message in.  When you save and exit, the commit completes.

You should make sure that the changes you are trying to commit have been added to the Git index; this determines what is committed.  See http://gitref.org/basic/ for details on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the comment character to something besides # like this:

```
git config --global core.commentchar "@"
```