# git bash: stuck after writing the message for commit

Tags: git, git-bash, git-commit, mingw-w64

I am trying to add a file to my github account using git bash. I have "commit", and I have entered the message required. But now, I am stuck (MINGW64). 
If I try :q, :quit, :quit!, nothing happens.
If I try CTRL+C, I can enter :quit! but in this case my commit is aborted.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ok, I have finally found a solution, and I post it (maybe it could help a newbie like me): esc then :wq. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599122/problems-with-entering-git-commit-message-with-vim[/link]

Answer (score 12):

It looks like your default editor is vi, so proper way to exit editor is:
First exit INSERT MODE (press ESC), then type ":wq" and press enter.

To avoid this kind of situation, you can set your default editor, for example:

```
git config --global core.editor emacs
```

to set `emacs` editor. More about git configuration [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

Comment: Many thnks! I will try that!

Answer (score 8):

You have to do this:

- write your message
- <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think whenever you press Esc button Git-Bash get stuck. I don't know how to avoid that .

However Esc + : + w + q    does seem to help a little bit, although most of the time I have to close the window !

Comment: I alias git to cmd/git.exe. `alias git="/c/Program\ Files/Git/cmd/git"` and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to use `\cmd\git.exe` instead of `mingw64` one. Orignally my `mingw64\bin\git.exe` stuck on commit or push as well, I aliased my git to the `\cmd\git.exe` and it fix it:

```
alias git="/c/Program\ Files/Git/cmd/git"
```

As a reference:

```
where git
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```