# How do I exit from the text window in Git?

Tags: git, vim

I am using Windows and before committing, Git wants me to enter a text message and a new text window appears.

[image: screenshot]

How can I exit from this?

I am trying to learn Git. So, a little help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git commit asking for comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668191/git-commit-asking-for-comment)

Comment: 5 years on, and with this being a [famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=1115545), would you like to accept an answer?

Answer (score 306):

Since you are learning Git, know that this has little to do with git but with the text editor configured for use. In vim, you can press `i` to start entering text and save by pressing `esc` and `:wq` and `enter`, this will commit with the message you typed. In your current state, to just come out without committing, you can do `:q` instead of the `:wq` as mentioned above.

Alternatively, you can just do `git commit -m '<message>'` instead of having git open the editor to type the message.

Note that you can also change the editor and use something you are comfortable with ( like notepad) - [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)

Comment: I recommend setting the editor to your favorite editor. Then use the command line version (git commit -m '...') when it fits, or let it launch your editor (TextMate, Notepad, whatever) when it doesn't

Answer (score 83):

There is a [default text editor](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#Your-Editor) that will be used when Git needs you to type in a message. By default, Git uses your system’s default editor, which is generally [Vi](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/) or [Vim](http://www.vim.org/). In your case, it is Vim that Git has chosen. See [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596805/78845) for details of how to choose another editor. Meanwhile...

You'll want to enter a message before you leave [Vim](http://www.vim.org/):

[<kbd>O</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#O)

...will start a new line for you to type in.

To exit (g)Vim type:

[<kbd>Esc</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_%3CEsc%3E)[<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#ZZ) or <kbd>Esc</kbd>[**`:wq`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:wq)<kbd>Return</kbd>.

It's worth getting to know Vim, as you can use it for editing text on almost any platform. I recommend the [**`Vim Tutor`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_01.html#tutor), I used it **many** years ago and have never looked back (barely a day goes by when I don't use Vim).

Comment: It's hard to see whether the 'O' is upper or lower case. A lower case 'o' causes the message to be written on the second row.

Comment: I guess it depends on your font. Hopefully the document to which it's hyperlinked will help disambiguate.

Comment: It's worth getting to know vim so you can quit it from a wide variety of applications that default to it.

Comment: In Inteliji Idea if you set Git as Terminal Escape just changes focus to code editor from Terminal, so the commits are still in edition mode, useless

Answer (score 62):

That's the [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) editor. Try `ESC` `:q!`.

Comment: Actually, it's Vim (see the title bar).

Comment: it worked all the time, by now it's always being in INSERT mode, I press ESC but nothing changes! it's still edits commits

Comment: it doesn't work if you added it as terminal for IntelliJ Idea. sometimes `CTRL + ESC` works but sometimes it closes fully the vim and you have to abort rebase because it failed to continue

Answer (score 17):

On Windows 10 this worked for me for VIM and VI using git bash

```
"Esc" + ":wq!"
```

or

```
"Esc" + ":q!"
```

Answer (score 14):

On windows I used the following command

```
:wq
```

and it aborts the previous commit because of the empty commit message

Comment: press The better the key `Esc` before

Comment: you can just start typing it until you exit somehow editing mode, it's very intuitive with IntelliJ Idea when using git as terminal

Answer (score 10):

First type

```
 i
```

to enter the commit message then press `ESC` then type

```
 :wq
```

to save the commit message and to quit.
Or type

```
 :q!
```

to quit without saving the message.

Comment: Thank you for a precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, simply pressing 'q' on the keyboard quits this screen.
I got it when I was reading help using '!help' or simply 'help' and 'enter', from the DOS prompt.

Happy Coding :-)