# How to exit from commit edit message in git?

Tags: git, nano

I usually commit by typing `git commit -m "initial"`.

By default GNU nano editor is choice in git config.editor on ubuntu Gnome 19.04

And i accidentally commit my change typing `git commit`enter and **GNU nano** appear for *editing commit message*. 
 
so How could i quit and return back to git terminal?

i went to look at this site : [How do I exit from the text window in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171356/how-do-i-exit-from-the-text-window-in-git) 
 but didn't work for me. 
[image: Git commit edit message]

Comment: Look at the bottom of the screen: Ctrl+O and Ctrl+X to save and quit.

Comment: You can exit by doing ctrl + x

Comment: The editor looks like `nano`. `^` refers to `Ctrl`.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
yes i am beginner and i don't know ^X is "ctrl+x". I typed ^X instead , so pretty confusing. I wasted much time on it. 
And This question will help other from saving time, just like me unaware of sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was unaware of the convention that `^` means to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

So the solution is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to abort, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to stop.

Comment: I don't use Nano (and would not recommend it to anyone) but I tried just now and mine doesn't seem to have ctrl-Z bound to anything. In many editors this suspends the editor and returns you to the shell, which means you can get back and continue editing where you suspended the editor with `fg`. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/nano#Suspension shows that this can be enabled separately in Nano, too, but needs to be explicitly configured.

Comment: https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/cheatsheet.html has the entire keyboard shodtcut list.

Answer (score 1):

Note:
nano is It's quite difficult to manage.It is better to get Git working with your code editor to make things simpler. Like for example if you use visual code you can add like this:

`git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`

or for atom:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

or for sublime:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"
```

Or you can search in Google how to associate you preferred your code editor with GIT.
Like this, you will edit more easily and once you close the tab or sometimes close the editor. The commit will be automatically.